# Expand DIV when at the bottom of the page jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Would it be possible to expand a div when the user is at the very bottom of the page?

I want to have a fixed expanding footer, which when the user has scrolled to the very bottom, it sets the default value of the footer height from 5px to, let's say, 110px, and shows more information...

I have looked high and low for something like this, but I cannot seem to find any useful tutorials or forums that can help me achieve what I am going for...

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="footer">
         &#169 2016 <a href="http://www.nerdtweak.com/">Nerdtweak.com</a> and <a href="http://www.yoieyo.com/">Yoieyo.com</a>
</div>
```

If anyone can help me achieve this, it would be great! Preferably in jQuery.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect that you are at the very bottom of page and set height of `footer` like following.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       //set your height here.
       $(".footer").height(110);
    } else {
       $(".footer").height(5);
    }
});
```

Comment: Aha... Nice man. I was struggling to find the formula... LoL.

Comment: can I then do `else { $(".footer").height(5px); }`?

Comment: Yes. I've added it. @CaelanGrgurovic

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do using this:

```
$(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight == $(document).innerHeight();
```

Have this:

```
$(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight == $(document).innerHeight()) {
      console.log("Expand Div");
      $("footer").addClass("expanded");
    } else {
      console.log("Contract Div");
      $("footer").removeClass("expanded");
    }
  });
});
```

**See Console: http://jsbin.com/cinisagela/edit?js,console,output**